# Mongodb not updating with data from in_forward plugin Fluentd

Tags: mongodb, fluentd

The scenario is as follows: I have sent data/packets from one fluentd node to another using out_forward and in_forward plugins and would like to save said data in mongodb.  To achieve this I have written said data to file and used the @tail protocol to tail the file as shown in my config. files. However, none of this data is available in mongodb which I dont understand. I would appreciate all help, hints. Thank you.

```
<source> #in forward
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match **>
@type file
path /var/log/td-agent/xyz.log
</match>

<source>
   @type tail
    path /var/log/td-agent/xyz.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/xyz.log.pos
    <parse>
    @type syslog
    </parse>
    tag mongo.syslog.access
</source>

<match mongo.**>
    @type mongo
    host localhost
    port 27017
    database syslog
    collection abc
    capped
    capped_size 1024m
    include_time_key true
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed...I simply ignored the intermediate soure and match blocks and wrote directly into the database